# How to implement editing existing items with Angular Material Chips

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Users should be able to edit existing chips.

Process could be like this:
 - The user double clicks on chip and this should start the edit mode.
 - The user should be able to change the chip value and then finalize the change with hitting enter.

My naive approach I tried:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-chips-edit-existing

I'm using Angular Material 5.1.0 with Angular 5.2.2.

The feature would look similarly as shown in this PR in AngularJS Material: https://github.com/angular/material/pull/7210

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It would be really great if someone posts the answer for this question, I need to implement the same

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhfiqn